# Detect app crashed during load / last time it was run?

Tags: ios, xcode, crittercism

I would like for my app to reset to standard settings if it crashed during startup. *Preferably also if it crashed last time it was run*.

EDIT: **Crittercism** has a `crittercismDidCrashOnLastLoad` method, but it only handles the case of crashing during load. It didn't work properly in the version of the library I used, but this has since been fixed.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Make 2 functions in your `AppDelegate.m` file:

```
void HandleException(NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"App crashing with exception: %@", exception);
    //Save somewhere that your app has crashed.
}

void HandleSignal(int signal) {
    NSLog(@"We received a signal: %d", signal);
    //Save somewhere that your app has crashed.
}
```

Then in your `-(BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` before anything else put:

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleException);

struct sigaction signalAction;
memset(&signalAction, 0, sizeof(signalAction));
signalAction.sa_handler = &HandleSignal;

sigaction(SIGABRT, &signalAction, NULL);
sigaction(SIGILL, &signalAction, NULL);
sigaction(SIGBUS, &signalAction, NULL);
```

Comment: Hmm, looks useful. Will it interact badly with Crittercism?

Comment: OK, I've tested this, and it will in fact disable Crittercism. I think I'll try to convince them to add this feature to their product then. Thank you for your advice, it was most helpful.

Comment: Good to know, I haven't used `Crittercism`, but probably they handle it in a similar way, this is also the way `TestFlight` handle the error logging. You can actually ask them how to use their uncaught exception handler together with yours...

Comment: Well, I wrote them a nice note about it. Will update the comments here when/if I hear from them.

Comment: I just tried this out, and I was wondering why HandleSignal() doesn't get called?

Comment: So @AndersSewerinJohansen, any updates in you talk with the Crittercism team?

Comment: Why isn't `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` enough, without `SIGABRT`, `SIGKILL`, and `SIGBUS`?

Comment: Swift answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441302/how-should-i-use-nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler-in-swift

Answer (score 8):

Using Crashlytics you then can set CrashlyticsDelegate to detect a crash on Swift or ObjC code.

```
import Fabric
import Crashlytics
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{
    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    return true
}

//MARK: - CrashlyticsDelegate

func crashlyticsDidDetectReport(forLastExecution report: CLSReport, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
{
    completionHandler(true)
}
```

From Crashlytics docs

> Your delegate must invoke the completionHandler, but does not need to
>   do so synchronously, or even on the main thread. Invoking
>   completionHandler with NO will cause the detected report to be deleted
>   and not submitted to Crashlytics. This is useful for implementing
>   permission prompts, or other more-complex forms of logic around
>   submitting crashes.
>
> Make certain that the delegate is setup before starting Crashlytics
>   with startWithAPIKey:… or via [Fabric with:…]. Failure to do will
>   result in missing any delegate callbacks that occur synchronously
>   during start.

Comment: The order of the following two lines is important. It will not work if you switch the order.

    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])