# What is the best way to track App log (FLOW), That app exactly Crash

Tags: ios, iphone

i took one Shared Instance that i define in my singleton. I am tracking this way

```
**2016-01-07 14:58:17.103** AppLogger | AppLoger Verson 1.0(1) | FATAL
--------------------------------------------
DEAA268B-982D-4B51-A717-1E8F5E698643 | iPhone Simulator | iPhone OS | 9.2 | iPhone | iPhone | x86_64 |  | Battry Level :-100% UnknownKey | WiFi | used: 3.114681 free: 0.258419 total: 3.373100

**2016-01-07 14:59:01.125*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]**

---------Exception Stack---------------------------

(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cd9de65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c816deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc81404 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 212
    3   AppLoger                            0x000000010c15d1e9 -[AppLogger mUploadTapped:] + 105
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010d1c5194 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010d3346fc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010d3349c8 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010d333af8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d23449b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d2351d0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d1e3b66 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d1bdd97 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ccc9a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ccbf95c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ccbee13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ccbe828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010fde5ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010d1c3610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    18  AppLoger                            0x000000010c15f4af main + 111
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011397992d start + 1
)
```

Comment: if you can.. use fabric.io crashlytics. its a great way figuring out crashes and it will direct you straight to the line where crashed.

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear.

Comment: I dont wanna a use 3rd party SDK,I wanna make own custom log tracker that can identify the crash or Flow of app when app exactly crash

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10886047/919545

Answer (score 0):

You want to know where exactly(code and class name) the app is crashing?

If so see the **crashlytics** its very easy to implement.

http://try.crashlytics.com/sdk/

Comment: this could have been a comment

Comment: I dont wanna a use 3rd party **SDK**,I wanna make own custom log tracker that can identify the crash or Flow of app when app exactly crash